# Add onClick to button inside custom status bar view

Tags: android, button, notifications, onclick, statusbar

So I've got the following custom view in my status:

[image]

How do I make the buttons (1, 2, 3, 4) clickable with onClick functions?

Plus how do I make the icon in the notification bar go away since this is an on going thing?

Thanks